# hmm baum welch algorithm Error in hmm$emissionProbs[state, observation[1]] : subscript out of bounds

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification, hidden-markov-models

I am trying to run Baum-Welch on EEG signal. I rounded the values so I can pretend it is a discrete signal just for simplification. So I have one column with rounded eeg and one with doctor scored sleep stages. 
like this:

doctor eeg

1   Wake  10

2   Wake  13

3   Wake  16

4   Wake  18

my code is here:

```
y = data$eeg
states = c("NonREM1", "NonREM2", "NonREM3", "REM", "Wake")
start_p = c(NonREM1 = 0,NonREM2 = 0,NonREM3 = 0, REM = 0, Wake = 1)
library(markovchain)
trans_p <- markovchainFit(data$doctor)$estimate
sleep.values <- unique(data[2])
hmm = initHMM(states, Symbols = sleep.values, startProbs=start_p, 
transProbs=trans_p)

baumWelch(hmm, observation = y, maxIterations=100, delta=1E-9, 
pseudoCount=0)
```

I also seem to fail to enter the emission probability matrix, so I leave it blank. When I fill it I get

Error in E[, ] <- emissionProbs[, ] : 
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

Can someone explain to me what is wrong? I am stuck on this the whole afternoon. :\

Comment: see [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11857598/r-error-number-of-items-to-replace-is-not-a-multiple-of-replacement-length-r)

Comment: It is possible that you raise the data egg or at least show a sample.